# Cloud data fusion Permission denied due to datastream.connectionProfiles.discover

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, service-accounts, google-cloud-data-fusion, data-stream, google-datastream

I am trying to create a cloud data fusion replication job from oracle to bigquery. Receiving the below error.

> Failed to connect to the database due to below error :
> io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission
> 'datastream.connectionProfiles.discover' denied on
> 'projects/<>/locations/us-central1/connectionProfiles'

[image]

Following the steps mentioned in the [official google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/oracle-to-bigquery).

I was able to [grant the Datastream Admin](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/oracle-to-bigquery#grant_permissions_to_service_accounts) role to the dataproc service account.
The cloud data fusion service account is not available in this project's IAM page. Not sure how to assign "Datastream Admin role" to the data fusion service account.
[image]

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Found it we assign roles by the above way.